# A formula for a special function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ be a function.
$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+s}$$

> Does function $f$ can be expressible in a different way? Is it expressible by some compositions of elementary functions?

Let me write what do i mean. The problem comes from given equation:

$$\pi\cot(\pi s) = \frac{1}{s}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n-s}+\frac{1}{n+s})$$

I suspect that it is not allowed to express this equation in following way, however it may help

$$\pi\cot(\pi s) = \frac{1}{s}+f(s)-f(-s)$$

After some calcultions, we have an equivalent(?) problem:

> Solve find function $F$ so that $S\cot(S) - 1 = F(S)+F(-S)$

Where $S=s\pi$
If we have a solution we may calculate $f(s)=\frac{F(s)}{s}$

Comment: The sum for $f$ is never convergent, right?

Comment: your sum for the cotangent is not correct as it needs $\frac{1}{s-n}$. As stated the sum doesn't converge since $(\frac{1}{n-s}+\frac{1}{n+s})=O(\frac{1}{n})$

Answer (score 2):

not sure that is what you want but one can easily show that if $\psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ is the logarithmic derivative of the Gamma function, one has:

$-(\psi(z)+\gamma+\frac{1}{z})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{z+k}-\frac{1}{k})$, so for example $\pi \cot \pi z=\psi(1-z)-\psi(z)$ and $\psi$ gives sort of half the series of the cotangent as noted

Answer (score 1):

The series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n-s}+\frac1{n+2}\right)$$converges for each $s\in\mathbb C\setminus(\mathbb N\cup-\mathbb N)$. On the other hand, the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+s}$$*never* converges. So, your function $f$ is not really a function (or, to be more precise, its domain is $\emptyset$).